# Iterator issues continue

Tags: c++, iterator, memory-address

I have bug checked this code considerably now and made sure I am outputting the 'correct' things to outline the problem. The iterator never points at the list at all, but another bunch of addresses which happily contain the correct data.

I have two questions:

1 =  given the form of the couts, am I outputting the correct items to investigate why this loop is not exiting ;

2 = if(1)  then what is going on to produce this output and do you have any advice to further my pointer knowledge (I have used this for loop format many times before and this as never happened ;

/questions

code :

```
#include "neutronFileReader.h"

using namespace std ;

neutronFileReader::neutronFileReader()
{
}

list<vector<float> > neutronFileReader::spectrum(char* filename)
{
ofstream addresses ;
addresses.open("adresses.txt") ;
ifstream fin(filename) ;
string binhi, binlo ;
list<vector<float> > neutronSpectrum ;
list<vector<float> >::iterator nS ;
vector<float> EnergyProbability ;

while(!fin.eof())
{
    EnergyProbability.clear() ;
    getline(fin, binlo, ' ') ;      //get the binlo string
    getline(fin, binhi, ' ') ;      //get the binhi string

    EnergyProbability.push_back(atof(binhi.c_str())+(atof(binhi.c_str()) -  atof(binlo.c_str()))/2) ; //store middle of bin as emission Energy

    getline(fin, binlo) ;       //try not to waste memory space

    EnergyProbability.push_back(atof(binlo.c_str())) ; //store emnission probability
    neutronSpectrum.push_back(EnergyProbability) ; //put the vector in the list
 }

 for(nS = neutronSpectrum.begin() ; nS != neutronSpectrum.end() ; nS++)  //go through the neutron spectrum
 {
     EnergyProbability = (*nS) ;
     addresses << &neutronSpectrum.begin() << " : " << &(*nS) << " : " << &neutronSpectrum.end() << endl ;    // print energy & prob to screen
     cout << &neutronSpectrum.begin() << " : " << &(*nS) << " : " << &neutronSpectrum.end() << endl ;
 }

 return neutronSpectrum ;
 }
```

and here is the output:

```
0x28fbc4 : 0x510c38 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510c58 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510c78 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510c98 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510cb8 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510cd8 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510cf8 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510d18 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510d38 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510d58 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510d78 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510d98 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510db8 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510dd8 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510df8 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510e18 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510e38 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510e58 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510e78 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510e98 : 0x28fbc0
0x28fbc4 : 0x510eb8 : 0x28fbc0
```

thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems to be working ok then (according to the last example).

It reaches the last element and then stops (the ones with the while never reach the last element because they fail the condition on the last element).

The key here is that .end() and .back() point to different things so that difference of addresses is to be expected.

.back() references the last element of the list.
.end() references a past-last-element that serves to stop the cycle ONLY after the last element was handled (as opposed to what happens with the:

```
while(&(*nS) != lastListElement) {
/*...*
}
```

that results in the cycle stopping BEFORE analyzing the last element.

From what I could gather your only problem was with the output of the addresses right? Or is the cycle not exiting where it is supposed to?

Comment: It wasn't, now it is due to your help, in fact it was behaving properly after one post. *embarassed. However this back and forth has greatly improved my understanding of iterators so thank you VERY much Revolt, am sorry for wasting your time. Hope you got something out of it too!

Comment: Indeed! Last time I messed with STL containers (hell, last time I messed with C++) was 2 years ago so it served as a refresher. Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but don't the 1st and 3rd column represent the pointers to the iterator instances returned by begin() and end() rather than the pointers to the objects (of the list) themselves?

Comment: that is great info, thanks! Changing code now, but how? am replacing with: &(*neutronSpectrum.begin()) is that correct? learning pointer behaviour is a difficult task (when you are trying to write real code at the same time) :)

Comment: I'd assume your solution &(*neutronSpectrum.begin()) is indeed the right approach. It'd dereference the iterator returning the item it is pointing to and then you get its memory address using the & operator.

Comment: Althogh this has been boosted up, it is not the best answer, though revolt did supply that also. Is below and refers to the .back() method of list and does not solve issue. (gives much greater understanding of it)... Thx Revolt!

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this myself but it seems that the iterator returned by [list.end()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/end/) doesn't point to a valid element. It points to the past-the-end element.

So that we can correctly understand what is going on you should output [list.back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/back/) which does indeed point to the last element on the list. Note that list.back() doesn't return an iterator but a direct reference to the last item (so you should simply print what is returned without dereferencing).

Comment: Yep, you are right. As soon as I had posted the below I began to play around with the .back() method. Unfortunately I can't tell the iterator to end the loop there.

Comment: Yep, you are right. As soon as I had posted the below I began to play around with the .back() method. Unfortunately I can't tell the iterator to end the loop there. I tried various fiddles but the same result each time: C:\Users\morb\Documents\Programming\c++\collimatedNeutrons\neutronFileReader.cpp:35: error: no match for 'operator!=' in 'nS != lastListElement', and similar (replace lastListElement with a variety of attempts) Is there any way I can do this? Right now I am going to remove the iterator entirely and try to just use a normal pointer to move through the list. - That didn't work

Comment: I only suggested .back() for debugging purposes (for the cout). I wouldn't actually reccomend using it for the for loop but if you really want to try it you'd have to use it like this: for (...; &(*nS) != lastListElement; ...). This ofcourse assuming that lastListElement is the pointer to the last element on the list.